# how to automatically update Listview in qml when ListModel changed

Tags: listview, qml, listmodel

I have a problem that I use ListModel to save information that I read from database. But when the ListModel updated, the ListView did not update. my code as below:

ListModel{
id: selectedTempStationlistModel
}

I read my database as below and append records from database:

```
selectedTempStationlistModel.append({"id": idValue})
```

and my ListView like that :

```
**ListView{
    id: amr_view_three
    model: selectedTempStationlistModel
    height: 220
    width: 655
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Layout.columnSpan: 2
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    clip: true
    delegate: Component  {
        Item{
            width: amr_view_three.width
            height: 80
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: id
                font.family:"SimSun"
                font.pointSize: 16
            }
        }
    }
}**
```

My target only need to show **id** from databse to listview. each time I add one record in database, I checked my ModelList that already changed, however, the ListView does not update new data  of the model. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: could you please spend a little more time formatting the code. Also please try to minimize the code to only illustrate the issue.

Comment: Thank  folibis
. I edit my question. Please spend time to help me. Thank you so much. I also used as forceLayout() . But it also did not work. my version qt version is 5.12

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that other people can run.

Comment: Dear Mitch. Thank you for your support. Actually, I found my problem. I had a typo  of name Model List.

Answer (score 1):

Your view will not update automatically when you update the model, you need to emit the corresponding signals in order for your view to update, generally you would have a `update` function in your model that looks like something like this:

```py
def update(self, ...){
    self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
    # update your model
    self.layoutChanged.emit()
}
```

You need to emit [layouAboutToBeChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutAboutToBeChanged)
before you touch any model data, and after you update
emit [layoutChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged)

Answer (score 0):

Thank TOHO. Perhaps some cases the model can not update automatically, my case my model can update automatically. The reason is Because of  my  poor typo. Btw, I found something related to forceLayout() in some cases if model can not update automatically. Thank you for your time so much

Comment: sure dude! a little advise: 1.you commented with an answer, instead press add a comment. 2. here on stackoverflow ppls are cold (; so if you don't want a ban don't say thanks so often.. read more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment.
3. If you have found the answer for your question consider  posting it and mark it as the correct answer.